# No attached payment source error when creating Stripe customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am trying to follow some tutorials here, have encountered some errors. Hope someone could help me on this.

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError in Users::RegistrationsController#create

This customer has no attached payment source
```

Code:

```
attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

def save_with_payment
  if valid?
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
    self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
    save!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your request is, when you're creating a customer, you're sending in the wrong parameters.

It should be

`Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, source: stripe_card_token)`

Check [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#create_customer)

Comment: thanks for your response @Kedarnag Mukanahallipatna...I was able to solve it after a couple of hours after posting it..

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this error while following this tutorial. However, I solved it by simply using [Stripe's doc to create a
customer](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/customers#attaching-a-source-to-a-new-customer-object)

```
Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, source: stripe_card_token)
```

The below code worked for me.

```
    def save_with_subscription 
       if valid?
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, source: 
        stripe_card_token)
        self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
        save!
      end
    end
```